# Python Except 'socket' object has no attribute 'error'

Tags: python, sockets

I'm writing test script for a TCP Server in **Python 3.8.**

The script worka well, but now I'm tring to implemente a more efficient error catching in order to identify timeout error.

To do that I started to catch the errors and the timeout error for the socket connect.

This is my SocketConnect function:

```
def SocketConnect( host, port ):
    global socketHandle

    opResult = errorMessagesToCodes['No Error']

    # Set Socket Timeout
    socketHandle.settimeout(1)
    logging.debug("Connect")
    try:
        socketHandle.connect((host, port))
    except socketHandle.error as e:
        opResult = errorMessagesToCodes['Socket Error']
        logging.error("!!! Socket Connect FAILED: %s" % e)

    return opResult
```

The socket handler is valid and, in order to test the timeout, I disable the server.

After one second after the connect the code goes to the except but I get this error:

> socket.connect((host, port))
>
> socket.timeout: timed out
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> except socket.error as e:
>   AttributeError: 'socket' object has no attribute 'error'

Is there something missing?

Because I don't understand why socket object ha no attribute error. I think this is a standard error for socket interface.

Thanks in advance for the help.

UPDATE:
I tried to do a basic test (starting from a blank project): only a socket create and a socket connect (with a server not in listening mode) to simulate a timeout.

This is the code:

```
import socket
import logging

try:
    socketHandle = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
except socketHandle.error as e:
    logging.error("Socket Create FAILED: %s" % e)

socketHandle.settimeout(1)

try:
    socketHandle.connect(('localhost', 2000))
except socketHandle.error as e:
    logging.error("!!! Socket Connect FAILED: %s" % e)
```

The connect goes into timeout but I still get the error:

> except socketHandle.error as e:
>   AttributeError: 'socket' object has no attribute 'error'

I really don't know what is happening.

UPDATE 2:

I made some other tests, and if I use the try-catch inside the connect function I get the error but if I use the try catch in the main a did not get any error.

Best regards,
Federico

Answer (score 1):

The error is due to you redefining the module name `socket`; which is what contains `socket.error`. You are trying to access module level constants (in this case `error` from the socket module), from a socket object. You could also tighten the error handling to only catch a timeout. This may be needed anyhow, as it appears `socket.error` does not cover `socket.timeout`. Changing your socket name should solve the issue:

```py
def SocketConnect(socx, host, port ):
    opResult = errorMessagesToCodes['No Error']

    # Set Socket Timeout
    socx.settimeout(1)
    logging.debug("Connect")
    try:
        socx.connect((host, port))
    except socket.timeout as e:
        opResult = errorMessagesToCodes['Socket Error']
        logging.error("!!! Socket Connect FAILED: %s" % e)

    return opResult
```

Comment: Hi Robert, I changed the code as you suggested but I get the same error. Thanks

Comment: You are likely defining a socket object at a global level, can you share your entire code?

Comment: Yes exactly, I tring to define a global socket handler in order to shutdown the socket when the code crash with the module "atexit". I cannot share the code. Sorry

Comment: Well that is your problem, you can not rename the socket module and expect to access its members. Either change the name of your socket (as shown in the above example), use a context manager or try/except block instead of atexit, or import socket as something else

Comment: Is there a way to share a socket handle globally? I'm come from C language..So my python skill are not the best :)

Comment: Yes, the same way as any other global variable. Just dont name it ```socket```, and that is no worries :)

Comment: Oh, I do that and I called the global socket handler: "socketHandle" and I defined it in the main as socketHandle = None. Maybe the problem regards the facts that each function receive this handler as parameter and not using the global directive inside the function?